# How to add multiple records from POST in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I had a little difficulty making multiple record in Django. I found a solution myself, but I couldn't make it work. Can anyone with knowledge help?

form.html

```
<form action="" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for work_stations in ws %}
{% if work_stations.is_active %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="work stations1" aria-label="" name="ws1">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="work stations2" aria-label="" name="ws2">
     </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" >
</form>`
```

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
class Master_data(models.Model):
    
    ws1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=' ', blank=True)
    ws2= models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=' ', blank=True)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
    
from .models import Master_data
def createpost(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        posts = request.POST.getlist('post_list[]')
        Master_data.objects.all().values()
        post_list_data = posts
        for x in post_list_data:
            x.save()
    
        return render(request, 'main/cretedata.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'main/cretedata.html')
```

Comment: What is your view supposed to do, what problem do you encounter, what is the HTML form supposed to do?

Comment: The list data received via POST must be taken and recorded in the database (in a single table). I don't want to use a Djang form because, when i requesting the lists(form elements) appear in different amounts in each category .

Answer (score 0):

You Can use [Django Formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/formsets/)

Sample Code.
Assuming you already have model class

in forms.py

```
class WorkStationForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = WorkStation
        fields = "__all__"
```

views.py

```
from blog.forms import WorkStationForm
from django.forms import formset_factory
def home(request):
    ws_form_set = formset_factory(WorkStationForm, extra=2)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_set = ws_form_set(request.POST)
        if form_set.is_valid():
            form_set.save()
        else:
            print("form is not valid")

    context_dict = {
        "form_set": ws_form_set,
    }
    return render(request, "form.html", context_dict)
```

in html;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        {{form_set}}
                  <input type="submit" value="submit form">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did not want to use django formset on this page. Because the amount of data (form elements) to be entered varies in each category.
  I select a category and then the form elements appear. The number of elements varies in each category. It is more difficult for me to do this in the form set.

Comment: HTML Form need unique name to each element for identification at backend. if you want to procced with your original approach, you can make each element name unique by adding id to it. 
something like 
in html
<form action="" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for work_stations in ws %}
{% if work_stations.is_active %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="work stations1" aria-label="" name="ws{{work_stations.id}}">
    </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" >
</form>`

Comment: There is no problem on the HTML side, it works. My problem is about what to write in views.py. How do I need to save the data list received via POST into the table?